# Why is link not working? undefined local variable path or method ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I cannot get my link to work:
Users can post job listings. Other users can view the job listing and click on apply.
Now a form should appear for the user to fill out some information. However I cannot get the path and route file right. 
This is the link in show.html.erb that's now working

```
<li><%= link_to "Apply Now", listing_apply_path(id: listings.id) %></li>
```

The form is under views/listings/apply.html.erb

listings/show.html.erb

```
<div class="show_listing">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><%= @listing.title %></h3>
        <h3><%= @listing.location %></h3>
        <p><%= @listing.description %></p><br>
        <div class="center">
        <li><%= link_to "Apply Now", listing_apply_path(id: listings.id) %></li>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="show_link_position">
<% if current_user == @listing.user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path, class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', current_user, class: "btn btn-link" %>
</div>
```

listings_controller.rb

```
    def apply
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
      end
```

and routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories

  get 'notifications/index'

  get 'notifications/create'

    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :listings



  root 'static_pages#home'


      match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
      match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new',          via: 'get'
      match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via:'delete'
      match '/help',      to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
      match '/contact',   to: 'static_pages#contact',  via: 'get'
      match '/about',     to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get' 
      match '/new',     to: 'listings#new',   via: 'get' 
      match '/users/:name/:id', to: 'listings#show', via: :get, as: :user_listing
      match '/findjobs',     to: 'listings#index',   via: 'get' 
      match '/users/:name/:id/edit', to: 'listings#edit', via: 'get'
      match '/:id/apply', to:  'listings#apply', via: 'get'
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Coderhs has added something for you you also need to name that route so that you have a matcher for it like this:

```
 match '/:id/apply', to:  'listings#apply', via: 'get', as: :listing_apply
```

that way you will have access to the url helper `listing_apply_path`

also `match` and `via` is not needed you can just specify

```
get '/:id/apply', to: 'listings#apply', as: :listing_apply
```

`match` means any method (e.g. `POST`,`GET`,`PUT`,`DELETE`)

`get` means process `GET` requests.

`match` with `:via` means the same thing as `get` without it. I only use `via` in cases where I need 2 or more VERBS to got to the same place. Otherwise I just specify the method needed.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing

> Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security implications. In general, you should avoid routing all verbs to an action unless you have a good reason to.

**Update**

You asked

> Why do I need to tell routes here that I need the path as:listing_apply. Why didn't I have to do it for lets say the edit path?

the `resources` method creates these for you

```
resources :listings
```

generates following routes for you

```
listings     GET    /listings              listings#index
             POST   /listings/create       listings#create
new_listing  GET    /listings/new          listings#new
edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit     listings#edit
listing      GET    /listings/:id          listings#show
             PUT    /listings/:id          listings#update
             DELETE /listings/:id          listings#destroy
```

This will allow access to `listings_path`, `new_listing_path`, `edit_listing_path`, and `listing_path`. For the non named routes it uses the VERB (POST, PUT, DELETE) to determine routing

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much for your help and the explanation.
I wish I could mark both answers as correct! One more question: Why do I need to tell routes here that I need the path as:listing_apply. Why didn't I have to do it for lets say the edit path?

Comment: @user123 pick whichever one you want. I like to help people. Reputation points mean far less to me than the "Thanks" you put above.

Comment: Okay got it. I will make sure to read through it.  Could you kindly explain to me why I have to write @listing.id whereas for the edit path I only had to write listing.id? Also, Why do I need to tell routes here that I need the path as:listing_apply. Why didn't I have to do it for lets say the edit path?

Comment: @user123 well `listing` is an undefined local variable where as `@listing` is an instance variable you set up in the controller. For the first route you can just use `listing_apply_path(@listing)` and it will pull the `id` through a method called `to_param`. For the `edit_listing_path` this gets into rails magic using something called the `default_url_options` hash. Which is very confusing and has many questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<li><%= link_to "Apply Now", listing_apply_path(id: @listing.id) %></li>
```

you need to pass in the instance variable into the path, using listing is undefined inside of the view.

Comment: make sure that you set @listing inside of the controller

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't check the variable name when i copy pasted the code. I have edited the variable name

Comment: In my controller I've got
 def apply
 @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
        end

Is that right?

Comment: `listing_apply_path(@listing)` would suffice, as well.

Comment: @Coderhs and @RGB when I use 
listing_apply_path(id: @listing.id)
I get the error 
undefined method `listing_apply_path'
@pdobb I get the same error with listing_apply_path(@listing)

Comment: Modify your routes to `match '/:id/apply', to:  'listings#apply', via: 'get'`

Comment: thank you for you help.
Could you kindly explain to me why I have to write @listing.id whereas for the edit path I only had to write listing.id? Why is there a difference?